# OpenGL ES - managing video memory

Tags: java, optimization, opengl-es, vbo

I work on an embedded app for a system that has 1GB RAM and 128 MB dedicated video memory on a Vivante GPU.

My application is a 3d real-time representation of work being done by the system. The way it goes is that basically a car is moving on an infinite-plane type field, and draws a polygon behind it. That polygon can be complex - having gaps and holes, and it's updated rather frequently.

In other words, I create a mesh at runtime by triangulating the shapes that I receive from the maths module - and draw those as meshes.

I have done a bit of optimization of rendering - by splitting my "world" into squares and splitting the resulting mesh into those square chunks, later determining which chunks I need to draw and which are outside of frustum.

But as far as memory goes - so far I've been simply creating VBO's for vertex and index data, and that's it. I leave them therere and never touch them again - simply render the meshes when needed using those VBO's

The problem I ran into is that after a time, my program begins to stutter. It freezes for .5 a second or longer, and then runs smoothly for a few seconds again before freezing again.
***EDIT:*** Narrowed it down today to GPU overheating and lowering clock by 64 times. Not a software problem. But I still want to know general tips of memory management.

I nailed it down to my mesh creation (not any other calculations in my program). If I stop creating meshes - i.e. creating VBO's - the problem gets delayed or removed entirely, if I get to a point where I create no meshes at all.

I will note that in the time it takes the program to begin to stutter - I most definitely can not run out of video memory. 128 MB is too much to use in that time, I at most use a couple hundreds kilobytes. So I'm not actually even sure if it's video memory related or something else.

My problem is - I can't find good articles that describe what I actually need to do. All I know is that if I stop creating VBO's - the problem disappears for me.

I'm not sure which code could I put here as an example, so for now I'm putting none.

Any help?

Comment: So your app is constantly calling `glGenBuffers`, but never calls `glDeleteBuffers`? If so, then you'll be consuming ever increasing amounts of memory until it becomes a problem. Quickest fix would be to delete VBOs once they're no longer useful to you.

Comment: That's the problem - they are always useful. Because while they can move too far away outside frustum - it's not a given that the vehicle won't turn around and move back in range, so that they will need to be displayed again. I call glDeleteBuffers if I delete the mesh itself, obviously. So what SHOULD I do? Read the buffers back into RAM, delete VBO's and then load them back onto GPU when they become relevant? Say I've moved too far, I unload the VBO back into RAM and delete it. Keep only VBO's for meshes in range on the GPU?